# Are high values for c or gamma problematic when using an RBF kernel SVM?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, svm

I'm using WEKA/LibSVM to train a classifier for a term extraction system. My data is not linearly separable, so I used an RBF kernel instead of a linear one.
I followed the [guide from Hsu et al.](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf) and iterated over several values for both c and gamma. The parameters which worked best for classifying known terms (test and training material differ of course) are rather high, c=2^10 and gamma=2^3.
So far the high parameters seem to work ok, yet I wonder if they may cause any problems further on, especially regarding overfitting. I plan to do another evaluation by extracting new terms, yet those are costly as I need human judges.
Could anything still be wrong with my parameters, even if both evaluation turns out positive? Do I perhaps need another kernel type?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general you **have to** perform cross validation to answer whether the parameters are all right or do they lead to the overfitting.

From the "intuition" perspective - it seems like highly overfitted model. High value of gamma means that your Gaussians are very narrow (condensed around each poinT) which combined with high C value will result in memorizing most of the training set. If you check out the number of support vectors I would not be surprised if it would be the 50% of your whole data. Other possible explanation is that you did not scale your data. Most ML methods, especially SVM, requires data to be **properly preprocessed**. This means in particular, that you should **normalize** (standarize) the input data so it is more or less contained in the unit sphere.

Comment: All data was normalised. 7/10 steps of 10-fold-crossvalidation are finished and support the parameters. Support vector count is 4k of 30k; I know I want as few as possible, yet this seems to be okish? - Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

RBF seems like a reasonable choice so I would keep using it. A high value of gamma is not necessary a bad thing, it would depends on the scale where your data lives. While a high C value can lead to overfitting, it would also be affected by the scale so in some cases it might be just fine.

If you think that your dataset is a good representation of the whole data, then you could use crossvalidation to test your parameters and have some peace of mind.