# How to choose C and gamma AFTER grid search using libSVM (RBF kernel) for best possible generalisation?

Tags: machine-learning, kernel, svm, libsvm, cross-validation

I am aware of the abundance of questions asking about choosing the 'best' C and gamma values for SVM (RBF kernel). **The standard answer is a grid search, however, my questions starts after the results of the grid search.** Let me explain:

I have a data set of 10 subjects on which I perform leave-one-subject-out-xfold-validation meaning I perform a grid search on each left-out subject. In order to not optimise on this training data I do not want to choose the best C and gamma parameter by building the mean accuracy over all 10 models and search for the maximum. Considering one model within the xfold, I could perform another xfold only on the training data wihtin this model (not involving the left out validation subject). But you can imagine the computational effort and I do not have enough time atm for this.

Since the **grid search** for each of the 10 models **resulted in a wide range of good C and gamma parameters (difference between accuracy of only 2-4%, see Figure 1)** I thought about a different way.

**I defined a region within the grid, which only contains the accuracies that have a difference of 2% to the maximum accuracy of this grid. All other accuracy values with a difference higher than 2% are set to zero (see Figure 2).** I do this for every model and build the intersect between the regions of every model. This results in a much smaller region of C and gamma values that would produce accuracies within 2% of the max. accuracy for each model. However, the range is still rather big. **So I thought about choosing the C-gamma pair with the lowest C as this would mean that I am the furthest away from overfitting and closer to a good generalisation. Can I argue like that?**

---

**How would I generally choose a C and gamma within this region of C-gamma pairs, which all proofed to be reliable adjustments for my classifier in all 10 models?**
Should I focus on minimising the C parameter? Or should I focus on minimising the C AND the gamma paramater?

---

I found a related answer here ([Are high values for c or gamma problematic when using an RBF kernel SVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23391151/are-high-values-for-c-or-gamma-problematic-when-using-an-rbf-kernel-svm)) that says a combination of high C AND high gamma would mean overfitting. I understood that the value of gamma changes the width of the gaussian curve around data points, but I still cant get my head around what it practically means within a data set.

The post brought me to another idea. Could I use the number of SVs related to the number of data points as a criterium to choose between all the C-gamma pairs? A low (number of SVs/number of data points) would mean a better generalisation? **I am willing to loose accuracy as it shouldnt effect the outcome I am interested in, if I get in return a better generalisation (at least from a theoretical point of view).**

[image: Balanced accuries after grid search]

[image: Balanced accuries that follow my region and intersect criterium]

Answer (score 1):

Since linear kernel is a special case of rbf kernel. There is a method using linear SVM to tune C first. And bilinear tuning C-G pair later to save time.

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.141.880&rep=rep1&type=pdf